# The MANIFEST.MF file won't load when I compiled it on my macbook

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, manifest, manifest.mf

I created a simple test jar executable file, but when I tried to run it, it wouldn't work because it said that the Main-Class manifest attribute from jar.jar wouldn't load.  The manifest file (which was called manifest.mf) I typed up looked like this:
Main-Class: JarTest

and the compiler command looked like this:

jar cmf manifest.mf jartest.jar *.class

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: None of us can telepathically look inside your jar file and see whether it ended up containing a JarTest.class file at the top level, so we can't help you with this.

Comment: How did you try to run your java program?  like Behrang said it should be java -jar jartest.jar, also, tells us exactly what java said when you tried to run your program and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest file is case-sensitive and it should be named `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`.

To execute the JAR file, you should run `java -jar jartest.jar`.

Comment: I decompressed the jar file to see if I could figure out what the problem was, and the MANIFEST.MF was saved in the directory 'META-INF'. However, when I opened it with textedit to see if it was different from my original manifest.mf, it was.

Comment: I don't know what you are doing, but you can write the manifest file yourself and add it to META-INF manually. This way it will always be the same under all platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It's good to learn how to do this manually. As a debugging aid, you can use this handy [utility](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/manifesto) to examine your JAR's manifest, as built. It's also an example of how to use `ant` to create your manifest in a way that leaves less room for error.